# System.out.printf giving an error and I don't know why

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on a program that is a restaurant calculator and it relies on arrays.

I am receiving an error in the console about formatting, and it prevents the result from displaying. The lines in question are:

```
System.out.printf("\n%-10s%4d%10.2f\n", "Person#", "Age", "TotalBill"); 
...
System.out.printf("Grand total = $ %.2f\n" + grandTotal);
```

The full exception stack trace is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
    at BillRestaurant.main(BillRestaurant.java:191)
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class BillRestaurant {
    //Hardcode the prices of the meals & tax & discount
        private final double Soup = 2.50, Wings = .15, Burger = 4.95, ChickenSandwich = 5.95, Fries = 1.99, Pie = 2.95, IceCream = 2.99,
                SoftDrink = 1.50, Coffee = 1.00, Discount = 0.25, Tax = 0.05; 

        //Declare variables 
        private int age, soup, wings, burger, chickensandwich, fries, pie, icecream, softdrink, coffee;
        private double totalbill;

        public BillRestaurant()
        {
            //Sets every thing to zero
            this.age = 0;
            this.soup = 0;
            this.wings = 0;
            this.burger = 0;
            this.chickensandwich = 0;
            this.fries = 0;
            this.pie = 0;
            this.icecream = 0;
            this.softdrink = 0;
            this.coffee = 0;
            this.totalbill = 0;
        }

        public BillRestaurant(int age, int soup, int wings, int burger, int chickensandwich, int fries, int pie, int icecream, int softdrink, int coffee)
        {
            //Assigns the value of the parameter a to the field of the same name
            this.age = age;
            this.soup = soup;
            this.wings = wings;
            this.burger = burger;
            this.chickensandwich = chickensandwich;
            this.fries = fries;
            this.pie = pie;
            this.icecream = icecream;
            this.softdrink = softdrink;
            this.coffee = coffee;
            calcualteTotalBill();
        }
        private void calcualteTotalBill()
        {
            //Apply discount to teens and seniors, tax, and kids eat free to the Total bill
            if(age <= 12)
                totalbill = 0;
            else
                totalbill = soup * Soup + wings * Wings + burger + Burger + chickensandwich * ChickenSandwich + fries * Fries + pie * Pie + icecream * IceCream +
                softdrink * SoftDrink + coffee * Coffee;
            if((age >= 13 && age >= 18) || age >= 65)
                totalbill = totalbill - totalbill * Discount;
            if(age <=12 || (age > 18 && age <65))
                totalbill = totalbill + totalbill * Tax;
        }
            public double getTotalbill()
            {
                return totalbill;
            }
            public int getAge()
            {
                return age;
            }

    //Main Method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Declare variables
        int number, age, soup, wings, burger, chickensandwich, fries, pie, icecream, softdrink, coffee, count;
        int more = 0;

        //Ask how many people will eat
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Number of people: ");
            number = input.nextInt();
            BillRestaurant[] orders = new BillRestaurant[number];
            System.out.println("Every person who eats at this restaurant orders exactly three items.  Never greater, never fewer.");

            //Starts Placing the order. User needs to choose 3 items.
            for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                soup = 0;
                wings = 0;
                burger = 0;
                chickensandwich = 0;
                fries = 0;
                pie = 0;
                icecream = 0;
                softdrink = 0;
                coffee = 0;
                count = 0;
                System.out.println("Enter order for person " + (i + 1));
                System.out.print("Age ");
                age = input.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Soup ");
                soup = input.nextInt();
                if(soup > 0)
                    count++;
                System.out.print("Wings ");
                wings = input.nextInt();
                if(wings > 0)
                    count++;
                System.out.print("Burger ");
                burger = input.nextInt();
                if(burger > 0)
                    count++;
                if(count ==3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Order complete. ");
                    orders[i] = new BillRestaurant(age, soup, wings, burger, chickensandwich, fries, pie, icecream, softdrink, coffee);
                }
                else
                {
                System.out.print("ChickenSandwich ");
                chickensandwich = input.nextInt();
                if(chickensandwich > 0)
                    count++;
                if(count ==3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Order complete. ");
                    orders[i] = new BillRestaurant(age, soup, wings, burger, chickensandwich, fries, pie, icecream, softdrink, coffee);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print("Fries ");
                    fries = input.nextInt();
                    if(fries > 0)
                        count++;
                    if(count ==3)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Order complete. ");
                        orders[i] = new BillRestaurant(age, soup, wings, burger, chickensandwich, fries, pie, icecream, softdrink, coffee);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.print("Pie ");
                        pie = input.nextInt();
                        if(pie > 0)
                            count++;
                        if(count ==3)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Order complete. ");
                            orders[i] = new BillRestaurant(age, soup, wings, burger, chickensandwich, fries, pie, icecream, softdrink, coffee);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.print("IceCream ");
                            icecream = input.nextInt();
                            if(icecream > 0)
                                count++;
                            if(count ==3)
                            {
                                System.out.println("Order complete. ");
                                orders[i] = new BillRestaurant(age, soup, wings, burger, chickensandwich, fries, pie, icecream, softdrink, coffee);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.out.print("SoftDrink ");
                                softdrink = input.nextInt();
                                if(softdrink > 0)
                                    count++;
                                if(count ==3)
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Order complete. ");
                                    orders[i] = new BillRestaurant(age, soup, wings, burger, chickensandwich, fries, pie, icecream, softdrink, coffee);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    System.out.print("Cofee ");
                                    coffee = input.nextInt();
                                    if(coffee > 0)
                                        count++;
                                    if(count ==3)
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("Order complete. ");
                                        orders[i] = new BillRestaurant(age, soup, wings, burger, chickensandwich, fries, pie, icecream, softdrink, coffee);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("You order less than 3 items. Please try again. ");
                                        i--;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("\n%-10s%4d%10.2f\n", "Person#", "Age", "TotalBill");
        double grandTotal = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%-10d%4d%10.2f\n", (i + 1), orders[i].getAge(), orders[i].getTotalbill());
            grandTotal = grandTotal + orders[i].getTotalbill();
        }
        System.out.printf("Grand total = $ %.2f\n" + grandTotal);

        System.out.print("\nEnter 1 if someone else needs to order: ");
        more = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        }while(more == 1);
        }


}
```

Comment: which line the error pointed to ?

Comment: System.out.printf("\n%-10s%4d%10.2f\n", "Person#", "Age", "TotalBill"); and System.out.printf("Grand total = $ %.2f\n" + grandTotal);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. The 'd' format is not for Strings. In the heading you are trying to print 3 Strings:

"Person#", "Age", and "TotalBill".  These are Strings.

So, change your header output to just use Strings:

```
System.out.printf("\n%-10s%4d%10.2f\n", "Person#", "Age", "TotalBill");
```

e.g.,

```
System.out.printf("\n%-10s%4s%10s\n", "Person#", "Age", "TotalBill");
```

Then this line also looks suspect:

```
System.out.printf("Grand total = $ %.2f\n" + grandTotal);
```

I suspect you meant:

```
System.out.printf("Grand total = $ %.2f", grandTotal);
```